# Using Visual Studio and SourceSafe with Multiple Developers Each Having Their Own Custom Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

Everyone,

Is anyone aware of a way to use Visual Studio 2010 in combination with Visual SourceSafe in such a way that on a team with multiple developers each developer can have their own custom solution comprised of a group of projects that are checked into source control?  I basically need to check in the projects without the solution file so that each developer can then create a new solution in Visual Studio and add only the projects they need to work with.

If there is a way to do this, how do I manage the references between projects?  For a project contained in a solution, I would typically add a reference to another project in the solution, but in this scenario each developer could potentially have a different solution.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible.

You'll need to ensure that everyone is using the same directory structure and location path on their development machines.

You'll need to create a master solution with a directory that contains all projects.
Immediately below this you create your project directories. This is added to VSS.

Then each user ceates their own solution and places the solution directory under the the master solution i.e. at the same level as the master solution projects. They then select which projects they wish to use.

This will leave you with a directory structure like this:

```
MasterSolution
    Project1
    Project2
    Project3
    Solution_User1 (references Project1 and Project2)
    Solution_User2 (references Project2 and Project3)
```

It may seem a bit odd having the project directory at the same level as the solution directory, but it's the only way around it.

Remember its the `.proj` and `.sln` files that dictate what a project or solution includes and their reference paths.

A solution cannot reference another solution, but it can reference projects referenced by another solution.

This method is called the partitionioned single solution model by Microsoft.
Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx) for further examples.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the link.  It seems to be working reasonably well.  In the user solutions, we are losing the external references to the assemblies that were added by NuGet.  I tried to copy the packages folder and all of its contents to the same relative location as it exists in the master solution but no go.  Strangely, the Font settings are also getting hosed.  When I open a code file in the user solution, my fonts are huge!  If I can get around these issues, I will be where I need to be.